# Why jshell doesn't work in comint-mode?

Tags: comint, repl

When I try to run jshell using `(comint-run "/usr/bin/jshell")`, it presents me with the prompt but when I give it some input, the buffer gets frozen and I get no output.

Conversely when I try to run python using `(comint-run "/usr/bin/python")`, it presents me with the prompt and it works fine with whatever input I give.

Why is this happening? What is the difference here? I thought comint just redirects the stdin and stdout. What underlying mechanism makes it so that comint treats python and jshell differently?

Comment: Are you talking about https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm ?

Comment: If you use `M-x shell` and run `jshell` from that, do you get a different result?

Comment: With "shell" it stops working same as with comint. So I guess the issue here is the terminal emulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comint doesn't provide a fully-functional terminal replacement. It passes input from the user to the shell, and prints the output back to the screen. It can handle some escape sequences, but that's about it. Programs that require more sophisticated control of the terminal will not work properly under these conditions.

I don't have access to `jshell` locally, but from your description it sounds like it requires full terminal emulation, rather than the 'dumb terminal' features of `M-x shell`. You can test this by running it in `M-x term` instead.

See further pointers on the [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryShell).

Comment: This is not it. I ran jshell inside term and got no problems at all.

Comment: That's the point. Term provides full terminal emulation, which jshell needs to function properly. Shell doesn't. So we expect jshell to work  in term, but not in shell

Comment: I tried with shell, and what you are saying is true. It stopped working with shell.

To add more information to this. It seems that jshell is not good a handling dumb terminals from this [bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8176391)